# underscore.js how to get an element from a JSON object using _.filter

Tags: json, underscore.js

I have the following JSOn object ( Array of elements )

```
var roles = [
      {
        "label": "alpha",
        "children": [
          {"label": "role1","title": "role1","value": "1"},
          {"label": "role2","title": "role2","value": "2"}
        ]
      },

      {
        "label": "beta",
        "children": [
          {"label": "role3","title": "role3","value": "3"},
          {"label": "role4","title": "role4","value": "4"}
        ]
      },

      {
        "label": "delta",
        "children": [
          {"label": "role5","title": "role5","value": "5"},
          {"label": "role6","title": "role6","value": "6"}
        ]
      }
    ]
```

I am trying to get ( and later remove.. ) an element with a specific label

I defined a where object

```
var where = {key: 'label', value:"alpha"};
```

and I filter the object :

```
var filteredRoles = _.filter(roles, function (el) {
  return el[where.key] && _.isArray(el[where.key]) &&
       _.indexOf(el[where.key], where.value) >= 0;
});
console.log("found "+JSON.stringify(filteredRoles, null, 2));
```

but I cannot get it :   found = []

where am I wrong ?

thanks for feedback

Comment: el[where.key] is not an array in the sample data so _.isArray will return false

Comment: thanks ! I read it many times wo notice it ... too late in the night

Comment: add you comment as answer , if you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
var result = _.filter(roles, function(role) {
   return (role[where.key] === where.value) && _.isArray(role['children']);
})
```

here is a working [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/wWUCZ3m6YyNZZIYYIvuu?p=preview)